# Simple check URL of Google safe browsing for Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm building an Android application which allows people scan QR code and open its content if that is a URL. But before opening, I want to check it's a safe URL. I check Google Safe Browsing API, and it turns out I need to download and save malware and infected URL list, which's impossible for Android client.

There's another way with http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site= but this have two disadvantages:

1.It doesn't work with full URL or URL paramater:

**Work**: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://example.com

**Don't work**: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://example.com/abc/def?ghi=opq

2.It opens a web page which tell us URL is safe or not, but I'd rather want it return a HTTP status code: like 201 -> safe, 202 -> isn't safe (which is easier to process).

The first disadvantage's not much a problem, but the second's really annoying. Can anyone show me another way around? Really thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API that maybe solves all of your problems: http://code.google.com/apis/safebrowsing/

And here is an Java client implementation for it: http://code.google.com/p/jgooglesafebrowsing/

Comment: Really thank you. Google Safe Browsing Lookup API is the answer for my problem. But jgooglesafebrowsing library is not, that library is for server, or desktop app, not android app

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would suggest is to have a server side implementation and have an Rest api exposed. Your android app can act as a client for the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to `urlencode` your URL as you cannot have two `?` characters in the URL at the same time.

So your URL should looks like:

> `https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search?url=http:%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fabc%2Fdef%3Fghi%3Dopq`

In Java, you can use [`URLEncoder.encode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html).

See: [Java URL encoding of query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10786042/55075)