# Java URL encoding of query string parameters

Tags: java, http, url, encoding, urlencode

Say I have a URL

```
http://example.com/query?q=
```

and I have a query entered by the user such as:

> random word £500 bank $

I want the result to be a properly encoded URL:

```
http://example.com/query?q=random%20word%20%A3500%20bank%20%24
```

What's the best way to achieve this? I tried `URLEncoder` and creating URI/URL objects but none of them come out quite right.

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them come out quite right"?

Comment: I have used URI.create and replaced spaces with + in querystring. At the client site it converted + back to spaces when I selected the query strings. That has worked for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Java method that encodes a collection of parameters as a URL query component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405731/is-there-a-java-method-that-encodes-a-collection-of-parameters-as-a-url-query-co)

Comment: Why do you expect $ to be percent-encoded?

Answer (score 1350, accepted):

[`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html) is the way to go. You only need to keep in mind to encode *only* the individual query string parameter name and/or value, not the entire URL, for sure not the query string parameter separator character `&` nor the parameter name-value separator character `=`.

```
String q = "random word £500 bank $";
String url = "https://example.com?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(q, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

When you're still not on Java 10 or newer, then use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()` as charset argument, or when you're still not on Java 7 or newer, then use `"UTF-8"`.

---

Note that spaces in query parameters are represented by `+`, not `%20`, which is legitimately valid. The `%20` is usually to be used to represent spaces in URI itself (the part before the URI-query string separator character `?`), not in query string (the part after `?`).

Also note that there are three `encode()` methods. One without `Charset` as second argument and another with `String` as second argument which throws a checked exception. The one without `Charset` argument is deprecated. Never use it and always specify the `Charset` argument. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLEncoder.html) even explicitly recommends to use the UTF-8 encoding, as mandated by [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) and [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/appendix/notes.html#non-ascii-chars).

> All other characters are unsafe and are first converted into one or more bytes using some encoding scheme. Then each byte is represented by the 3-character string "%xy", where xy is the two-digit hexadecimal representation of the byte. **The recommended encoding scheme to use is UTF-8**. However, for compatibility reasons, if an encoding is not specified, then the default encoding of the platform is used.

#### See also:

- [What every web developer must know about URL encoding](https://www.talisman.org/%7Eerlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/)

Comment: There can be 2 types of parameters in URL. Query string ( followed by ?) and path parameter (Typically part of URL itself). So, what about path parameters. URLEncoder produces + for space even for path parameters. In-fact it just does not handles anything other than query string. Also, this behavior is not in sync with node js servers. So for me this class is a waste and cannot be used other than for very specific / special scenarios.

Comment: @sharadendusinha: as documented and answered, `URLEncoder` is for URL-encoded query parameters conform `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` rules. Path parameters don't fit in this category. You need an URI encoder instead.

Comment: As I predicted would happen ... users getting confused because obviously the problem is people need to encode more than just the parameter value. Its a very rare case that you only need to encode a parameter value. Its why I provided my "confused"  wiki answer to help folks like @sharadendusinha.

Comment: how to fix this using JSP tags ?

Comment: Why should I not encode the entire url (instead of just query parameters) ?

Comment: @WijaySharma: Because URL-specific characters would get encoded as well. You should only do that when you want to pass the entire URL as a query parameter of another URL.

Comment: +1 for providing the link to https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/lunatech%5Ewhat-every-webdev-must-know-about-url-encoding/#Introduction

Comment: This solution does not work (anymore?), as [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) special chars such as `-` or `.` are NOT encoded. Thus this is a pretty useless function.

Comment: ... for the specific task you had in mind, which is clearly not URL-encoding of query string parameters.

Comment: For at least Android 6, "StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString()" is not the way to go, use "StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()". Otherwise you get an exception
java.nio.charset.IllegalCharsetNameException: java.nio.charset.CharsetICU[UTF-8]

Answer (score 203):

I would not use `URLEncoder`. Besides being incorrectly named (`URLEncoder` has nothing to do with URLs), inefficient (it uses a `StringBuffer` instead of Builder and does a couple of other things that are slow) Its also way too easy to screw it up.

Instead I would use [`URIBuilder`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html) or [Spring's `org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.encodeQuery` or Commons Apache `HttpClient`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444112/how-do-i-encode-uri-parameter-values).
The reason being you have to escape the query parameters name (ie BalusC's answer `q`) differently than the parameter value.

The only downside to the above (that I found out painfully) is that [URL's are not a true subset of URI's](https://web.archive.org/web/20170303071003/adamgent.com/post/25161273526/urls-are-not-a-subset-of-uris).

Sample code:

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;

URIBuilder ub = new URIBuilder("http://example.com/query");
ub.addParameter("q", "random word £500 bank \$");
String url = ub.toString();

// Result: http://example.com/query?q=random+word+%C2%A3500+bank+%24
```

Comment: Why does it have nothing to do with URLs?

Comment: @Luis: `URLEncoder` is as its javadoc says intented to encode query string parameters conform `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as described in HTML spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#didx-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded. Some users indeed confuse/abuse it for encoding whole URIs, like the current answerer apparently did.

Comment: @LuisSep in short URLEncoder is for encoding for form submission. It is not for escaping. Its not the *exact* same escaping that you would use to create URLs to be put in your web page but happens to be similar enough that people abuse it. The only time you should be using URLEncoder is if your writing a HTTP client (and even then there are far superior options for encoding).

Comment: @BalusC "*Some users indeed confuse/abuse it for encoding whole URIs, like the current answerer apparently did.*". You assumed wrong. I never said I screwed up with it. I have just seen others that have done it, who's bugs I have to fix. The part that I screwed up is that the Java URL class will accept unescaped brackets but not the URI class. There are a lot of way to screw up constructing URLs and not everyone is brilliant like you. I would say that most users that are looking on SO for URLEncoding probably are "*users indeed confuse/abuse*" URI escaping.

Comment: Question wasn't about that yet your answer implies that.

Comment: Yeah it is. He is concatenating strings to make a URL. URLEncoder is for encoding to the mime type not for making URLs. I have no reputation interest (hence I marked this a wiki post and only want to steer people correctly).

Comment: Not sure why, but I just stumbled on this.  URLEncoder is correct (see W3C HTML 4.01 Specification).  The URL passed query parameters are to be encoded using the "default content type" of application/x-www-form-urlencoded.  Regardless of what the mime type was intended for, the rules of encoding for the mime type, is exactly what is expected for the query parameters.  in the OP's question "....?q="+value, the value must be encoded to this mime type.  The use or URLEncoder may not be the most efficient, but it used in this case for exactly it's intended purpose.

Comment: The URL specification is separate from the HTML spec. It's also has changed and just like HTML there is a newer spec.

Answer (score 115):

You need to first create a URI like:

```java
String urlStr = "http://www.example.com/CEREC® Materials & Accessories/IPS Empress® CAD.pdf"
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
```

Then convert that URI to an ASCII string:

```java
urlStr = uri.toASCIIString();
```

Now your URL string is completely encoded. First we did simple [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and then we converted it to an ASCII string to make sure no character outside US-ASCII remained in the string. This is exactly how browsers do it.

Comment: Thanks! It's stupid that your solution works, but built-in `URL.toURI()` doesn't.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with "file:///" (e.g.: "file:///some/directory/a file containing spaces.html"); it bombs with MalformedURLException in "new URL()"; any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You need to do something like this:

String urlStr = "http://some/directory/a file containing spaces.html";
    URL url= new URL(urlStr);
    URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
urlStr=uri.toASCIIString();
urlStr.replace("http://","file:///");

I have not tested it, but I think it will work.... :)

Comment: I have used this since I started in Android, but today I noticed that the + and the = in the query strings don't get encoded, any solution?

Comment: where do you want to have + and = sign in url ? can you give an example of such url ?

Comment: is it also possible to decode it back to the original?

Comment: @tibi you can simply use uri.toString() method to convert it to string instead of Ascii string.

Comment: The API I was working with didn't accept the `+` replacement for spaces, but accepted the %20 so this solution worked better than BalusC, thanks!

Comment: This is a correct way to encode the path component of the URL. It is not a correct way to encode query parameter names or values, which is what the question is about.

Comment: @user207421it encodes both path components and querry params. Have a look: URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());

Comment: This solution does not work! The query parameter are not encoded, only spaces are.

Comment: @Sim on the contrary, it double encodes the query containing escaped ampersands and delimiter ampersands

Answer (score 37):

[Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) 15 has now added [a set of straightforward URL escapers](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html).

Comment: These suffer from the same goofy escaping rules as `URLEncoder`.

Comment: not sure they have the problem. they differentiate for instance "+" or "%20" to escape " " (form param or path param) which `URLEncoder` doesn't.

Comment: This worked for me I just replaced call to URLEncoder() to call to UrlEscapers.urlFragmentEscaper() and it worked, not clear if I should be using UrlEscapers.urlPathSegmentEscaper() instead.

Comment: Actually it didnt work for me because unlike URLEncoder it doesnt encode '+' it leaves it alone, server decodes '+' as space whereas if I use URLEncoder '+'s are converted to %2B and correctly decoded back to +

Comment: Link update: [UrlEscapers](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/net/UrlEscapers.html)

Answer (score 9):

The code

```java
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/query?q=random word £500 bank $");
URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), IDN.toASCII(url.getHost()), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
String correctEncodedURL = uri.toASCIIString();
System.out.println(correctEncodedURL);
```

Prints

```
http://example.com/query?q=random%20word%20%C2%A3500%20bank%20$
```

What is happening here?

**1.** Split URL into structural parts. Use `java.net.URL` for it.

**2.**  Encode each structural part properly!

**3.** Use `IDN.toASCII(putDomainNameHere)` to [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) encode the hostname!

**4.** Use `java.net.URI.toASCIIString()` to [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), NFC encoded Unicode - (better would be NFKC!). For more information, see: *[How to encode properly this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768599/how-to-encode-properly-this-url/49778055#49778055)*

In some cases it is advisable to [check if the URL is already encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53776285/1485527). Also replace '+' encoded spaces with '%20' encoded spaces.

Here are some examples that will also work properly

```
{
      "in" : "http://نامه‌ای.com/",
     "out" : "http://xn--mgba3gch31f.com/"
},{
     "in" : "http://www.example.com/‥/foo",
     "out" : "http://www.example.com/%E2%80%A5/foo"
},{
     "in" : "http://search.barnesandnoble.com/booksearch/first book.pdf",
     "out" : "http://search.barnesandnoble.com/booksearch/first%20book.pdf"
}, {
     "in" : "http://example.com/query?q=random word £500 bank $",
     "out" : "http://example.com/query?q=random%20word%20%C2%A3500%20bank%20$"
}
```

The solution passes around 100 of the test cases provided by [Web Platform Tests](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/url/resources/urltestdata.json).

Answer (score 8):

Using [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)'s [UriComponentsBuilder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html):

```
UriComponentsBuilder
        .fromUriString(url)
        .build()
        .encode()
        .toUri()
```

Comment: For the spring users, confirming this solution work well !!!

Answer (score 7):

The [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) library provides a neat option for building and encoding query parameters.

##### With HttpComponents 4.x use:

[URLEncodedUtils](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/org/apache/http/client/utils/URLEncodedUtils.html#format(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

##### For HttpClient 3.x use:

[EncodingUtil](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/util/EncodingUtil.html#formUrlEncode(org.apache.commons.httpclient.NameValuePair%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: The link for "URLEncodedUtils" is broken (404).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a method you can use in your code to convert a URL string and map of parameters to a valid encoded URL string containing the query parameters.

```
String addQueryStringToUrlString(String url, final Map<Object, Object> parameters) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    if (parameters == null) {
        return url;
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Object, Object> parameter : parameters.entrySet()) {

        final String encodedKey = URLEncoder.encode(parameter.getKey().toString(), "UTF-8");
        final String encodedValue = URLEncoder.encode(parameter.getValue().toString(), "UTF-8");

        if (!url.contains("?")) {
            url += "?" + encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue;
        } else {
            url += "&" + encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue;
        }
    }

    return url;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Android, I would use this code:

```
Uri myUI = Uri.parse("http://example.com/query").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("q", "random word A3500 bank 24").build();
```

Where `Uri` is a `android.net.Uri`

Comment: This is not using the standard Java API. So please specify library used.

Comment: This is the simplest solution to be used in an Android project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just needed to pass the whole URL and encode only the value of each parameters.
I didn't find common code to do that, so (!!) so I created this small method to do the job:

```
public static String encodeUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    if (url == null || !url.contains("?")) {
        return url;
    }

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String rootUrl = url.split("\\?")[0] + "?";
    String paramsUrl = url.replace(rootUrl, "");
    List<String> paramsUrlList = Arrays.asList(paramsUrl.split("&"));
    for (String param : paramsUrlList) {
        if (param.contains("=")) {
            String key = param.split("=")[0];
            String value = param.replace(key + "=", "");
            list.add(key + "=" +  URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
        }
        else {
            list.add(param);
        }
    }

    return rootUrl + StringUtils.join(list, "&");
}

public static String decodeUrl(String url) throws Exception {
    return URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
}
```

It uses [Apache Commons'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Commons#Commons_Proper) *org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils*.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this：

   ```
    URLEncoder.encode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
   ```

   or this:

   ```
    URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
   ```
2. You can use the following code.

   ```
    String encodedUrl1 = UriUtils.encodeQuery(query, "UTF-8"); // No change
    String encodedUrl2 = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8"); // Changed
    String encodedUrl3 = URLEncoder.encode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName()); // Changed

    System.out.println("url1 " + encodedUrl1 + "\n" + "url2=" + encodedUrl2 + "\n" + "url3=" + encodedUrl3);
   ```

Comment: Not correct. You have to encode the parameter names and values separately. Encoding the entire query string will also encode the `=` and `&` separators, which is not correct.

Comment: The UriUtils.encodeQuery() is missing the management of java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException